# Как исключить повторные нажатия кнопок

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Вопрос в следующем: как можно сделать так чтоб исключить повторное нажатие кнопки до нажатия другой кнопки? Например если уже нажат старт то его нельзя повторно нажать до нажатия кнопки стоп, со стопом аналогично

```
from telebot import types 

@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def message_reply(message):
    if message.text == "Старт":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Старт')
    elif message.text == "Стоп":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Стоп')
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Юзайте `register_next_step_handler`

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add("Старт", "Стоп")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "press but", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_but_start_stop)

# без декоратора
def get_but_start_stop(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "Старт":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Старт')
    elif message.text == "Стоп":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Стоп')
```

И чтобы наверняка, можно сделать  еще и так, вместо того маркапа который выше

```
markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True).add("Старт", "Стоп")
```